# How to change Brightness and Contrast with one UISlider with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics, cifilter

I am working on a Photo Filter App. I want to change Brightness and Contrast with a single slider. I can change them but when I jump to Contrast I loose Brightness changes. Wow can I keep the Brightness applied image and then continue with Contrast change.

```
 if sender.tag == 0 {
        
       
        self.coreImage = CIImage(image: (originalImage.image!))!
        
        
        let filter2 = CIFilter(name: "CIColorControls" )
        filter2!.setValue(coreImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
        filter2?.setValue(sender.value, forKey: kCIInputBrightnessKey)
        
        brightnessValue = sender.value
        
        
        filter2!.setValue(coreImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
        let filteredImageData2 = filter2!.value(forKey: kCIOutputImageKey) as! CIImage
        
        let filteredImageRef = ciContext.createCGImage(filteredImageData2, from: filteredImageData2.extent)
        let imageForButton = UIImage(cgImage: filteredImageRef!)
        
        
        
        originalImage.isHidden = true
        imageToFilter.image = imageForButton
    }
    
    else if sender.tag == 1 {

        
        self.coreImage = CIImage(image: (originalImage.image!)) ?? CIImage()
        
        let filter2 = CIFilter(name: "CIColorControls" )
        filter2!.setValue(coreImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
        filter2?.setValue(sender.value, forKey: kCIInputContrastKey)
        
        filter2!.setValue(coreImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
        let filteredImageData2 = filter2!.value(forKey: kCIOutputImageKey) as! CIImage
        
        let filteredImageRef = ciContext.createCGImage(filteredImageData2, from: filteredImageData2.extent)
        let imageForButton = UIImage(cgImage: filteredImageRef!)
        
        
        
        originalImage.isHidden = true
        imageToFilter.image = imageForButton


        }
```

and the following code controls the button and what to change

```
if (Lb == "Brightness") {
        sliderColor.tag = 0
        sliderColor.minimumValue = -1.0
        sliderColor.maximumValue = 1.0
        sliderColor.value = 0.0
        
    
        
    } else if (Lb == "Contrast") {
        sliderColor.tag = 1

        
        sliderColor.minimumValue = 0.0
        sliderColor.maximumValue = 4.0
        sliderColor.value = 1.0
        
        
    }
```

I am aware of it is caused by the fact that I use originalImage everytime I change Brightness or Contrast. But if I change it to imageToFilter things get sloppy.

Any ideas?

Comment: I think you have used two slider but have one action right or wrong?

Comment: No, one slider. But I forgot the line where I update slider.tag to control which effect is applied at that moment.

Comment: You can use two var to track your both value for Brightness and Contrast and then you can use it. Or second way is to keep using the same CIFilter for both actions instead of creating different for each one.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but, only using same CIFilter does not seem to work :(

Comment: You probably used the original image. You should need to use the output image of the CIFilter.

Comment: Yes. But if I use output image of the CIFilter instead of original, each time slider changes it tries to update filtered image and it doubles the effect..

Comment: Then it better to use two var and set and update those two var with slider value. when you move the slider any one apply both filter key with track value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have to keep reference and track for both filter key-value and apply both key filters at the same time while slider value changes.

Here is the demo code.

Note: As this is just a demo I used force unwrapping. You need to handle nil value.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var imageToFilter: UIImageView!
    
    public var brightness : Float = 0.0
    public var contrast : Float = 1.0
    
    var filter: CIFilter? = CIFilter(name: "CIColorControls")
    var originalImage = UIImage(named: "image_name")
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    
    func applyImageFilter(for image: UIImage) -> UIImage? {
        
        guard let sourceImage = CIImage(image: image),
              let filter = self.filter else { return nil }
        
        filter.setValue(sourceImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
        
        filter.setValue(self.contrast, forKey: kCIInputContrastKey)
        filter.setValue(self.brightness, forKey: kCIInputBrightnessKey)
        
        
        guard let output = filter.outputImage else { return nil }
        
        guard let outputCGImage = CIContext().createCGImage(output, from: output.extent) else { return nil }
        
        let filteredImage = UIImage(cgImage: outputCGImage, scale: image.scale, orientation: image.imageOrientation)
        
        return filteredImage
    }
    
    @IBAction func sliderValueChangeAction(_ sender: UISlider) {
        if sender.tag == 0 {
            self.brightness = sender.value
        
        } else if sender.tag == 1 {
            self.contrast = sender.value
        }
        
        imageToFilter.image = self.applyImageFilter(for: originalImage!)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a new `CIFilter` every time the value changes. The new filter doesn't know the previous setting. So the easiest way to solve this is to only create one `CIFilter` instance outside of the method (for instance as an instance variable) and only change the filter's brightness or contrast value in your slider callback. It should remember previous values this way.

Comment: Thank you, this totally makes sense. I tried to create a global CIFilter instead of creating every time. But still I have the same problem. May I ask if I do something wrong when outputting and displaying the image?

Comment: That seems to be fine. 